# User 'app@sharepoint' doesn't exist in UPA by UPN or SID, and user with this SID was not found in AD

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile-service, provider-hosted-app

I am having an issue on Sharepoint Online(Provider-hosted app) with calling User Profile REST API using AppOnlyAccessToken. My app has the feature to give permission on the fly to 'AllProfiles.Manage' scope. It managed to works with User + App token where I am getting Manager from User Profile but when I tried using AppOnlyAccessToken, it just throws me the error below:

Link to rest api call:

> https://test.sharepoint.com/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='Manager')?@v='i%3a0%23.f%7cmembership%7cuser01%40test.onmicrosoft.com

**Additional information**:

> Internal Server Error - {"error":{"code":"-1,
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserNotFoundException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"User
>   'i:0i.t|00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000|app@sharepoint' doesn't
>   exist in UPA by UPN or SID, and user with this SID was not found in
>   AD."}}}'

Anyone has any solutions to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact solution, but I can give some clues for which I've encountered this behavior

1. The `ClientSecret` for the Add-in has expired and needs to be regenerated (default is one year valid)
2. You need to explicitly create a user profile from your SharePoint Admin Center; as the error says
3. You have ADFS to connect your on-prem with Online domain. This error started to occur since the moment ADFS was enabled

Can you verify / confirm the items above?